# is a lot of research-level math useless in the "real world"?

Tags: soft-question, career-development

I'm a Ph.D. student in functional analysis, and struggling to understand why most research-level math in FA is useful.  I talked to my advisor about this, and his response was, quite literally, to shrug his shoulders.  In so many words, he said that he agrees with me that FA research is mostly useless, and suggests that I ignore the problem until I'm sufficiently well-established in the FA community.

Please don't misunderstand this question as suggesting that FA itself is useless.  Clearly it is extremely useful, and there are even examples, albeit uncommon, of very useful cutting-edge FA.

Instead, let me give a specific example of what I am talking about.  In a presentation about Ted Odell's work on spreading models, it was asked (my paraphrase):

*Assume $\ell_1$ does not isomorphically embed into a Banach space $X$, and all asymptotic models generated by weakly null arrays in $X$ are equivalent to the $c_0$ basis.  Is it necessary that $X^*$ is both separable and asymptotically-$c_0$?*

This is a difficult problem, and anyone who solves it will be rightly praised as an intelligent and clever mathematician.  But are such "clever" mathematicians really contributing in a significant way to human knowledge?

In some of my published papers, I have solved some "problems" in FA which are roughly on par with the above example.  This left me feeling very proud.  And yet, despite the recognition it has earned me in the FA community, I feel like I have really just been playing a game---the game of pandering to higher-ups ransoming postdocs.

With all this in mind, I suggest the following questions.

(1)  Should a math researcher prefer to investigate issues for which there are no immediate practical applications?

(2)  Do higher-ups (i.e., people on hiring committees) care about math research which has no obvious practical application?  *Should* they?

Comment: Note:  my first down-vote was posted within about 1-3 seconds of posting the above question.  I'm not sure what to say about this.  Thankfully, a +1-vote offset it after about a minute.

Comment: I have voted to close this as being primarily opinion-based. (And I’m already the third to do so.)

Comment: Can you please explain your reasoning?

Comment: Most math is good for nothing but applications to math.

Comment: (You need to use `@Brian` to be sure that I see a comment.) Look at your two numbered questions. The first and the second half of the second are unambiguously matters of opinion.

Comment: This really isn't an appropriate question for this site, sorry. It is opinion based. That does not mean it is a bad question or something you shouldn't think about, but it is just appropriate for here.

Comment: @David: And it’s hard to know what will eventually prove to have other applications — consider Hardy and number theory. We all know that most won’t, but a broad base better supports the whole enterprise.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Although I certainly understand how a person would expect questions like the above to be opinion-based, I think those expectations ignore what is actually going on.  At a minimum, by voting to close on such grounds, you are saying that any answer to (1) is a matter of opinion. Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: @user270237: Yes, of course: any answer to $(1)$ obviously *is* a matter of opinion.

Comment: The answers are no and yes and yes.

Comment: It's not that these questions are uninteresting. It's that this is not the correct forum for them, as they are currently stated.

Comment: Some math, now considered useful, was at one time considered useless.

Comment: @Brian I'm so disappointed.  I can't believe that questions such as (1) have been deemed "opinion-based".  Perhaps it is because I do not regard common sense as on par with personal opinion.

Comment: I agree this question is opinion-based, but I bet you could get some very thoughtful answers if it is left open, so I won't vote to close. (I also don't like the idea of us not trying to tell people why we do what we do, even though that is not a mathematical question.) Note, however, that your question could just as well be asked of most fields in academia, except the sciences and engineering (though even some basic science is susceptible to this question). Think about dissertations in history, English, philosophy, linguistics, even economics, etc.

Comment: And the answer to the first part of (2) is that it obviously depends, on what field you're in and what counts as "practical." Perhaps you should consider moving into applied math.

Comment: @user270237: People demonstrably do have different opinions on the subject, and there is no objectively right answer; that makes it a matter of opinion. (My own opinion, for what it’s worth, is that one should ideally do the research that interests one, irrespective of its possible use.)

Comment: (1) Most math researchers I know study things which do not have immediate practical applications (2) It depends on the position you are applying to. Research in fundamental math is present, but in some cases working on applied math is required. Whether you like it or not the question is opinion based. Most researchers love doing their stuff even if they do not produce any practical results. Even if our work is not "justified" in the eyes of some people think: 1. Are you sure your work won't be very useful someday? 2. Can someone else do what you do without years of hard training?

Comment: Math Stack Exchange has a Career Development tag.  If (1) is not an appropriate topic, the Career Development tag would not exist.  The fact that the tag exists means that the question is appropriate.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/175847/how-does-one-justify-funding-for-mathematics-research and http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/why-fund-the-research-in-pure-mathematics and likely thee are some more.

Comment: @Paul that argument is made often but does not hold water. For one thing, many a user just can create a tag on a whim. If no one pays attention and deletes it, the tag exists. This is not quite the case with this tag, but first there was some shift over time somewhat related to the advent of  [academia.se], second just that some questions on Career Dev are on-topic does not mean that all are. That said, I do personally believe that some users judgment may be affected by their personal dislike of OP's view.

Comment: If it is more difficult building teams to try and build stuff with it, it may seem there do not exist many applications - as not many applications get built, but in fact there's rather a problem related not to the work not being potentially useful but rather identifying, allocating and managing the resources to do something with it. Supposedly advances in math branches like optimization could help us improve that. If we can just allocate the ... oh well ..

Comment: Do you mean (1) as written, namely a researcher should *prefer* subjects with *no* application? It's not unreasonable in itself but maybe more extreme than what you intended.

Comment: Thank you all for the interesting comments.